# How do I get entire Data Layout for a class, using libclang?

Tags: c++, libclang

I am trying to generate the Data Layout for a class.  Specifically, I want

1. the size of an object of type `X`
2. the alignment of an object of type `X`
3. the offset within an object of type `X` of each data component (base or member).

I can easily enough get 1 and 2.  I can also easily get 3 for each member of `X`.

In addition, given a class, I can obtain the cursor for each of its base classes, and can traverse that to the root and build an inheritance graph.

However, I can't figure out how to get the offset of each base of class `X`.

Ultimately, I want the offsets of all members of `X`, and all the members of all bases of `X`, with their offsets relative to `X`.

Basically, I want the information that is described in [Chapter 2: Data Layout](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#layout) from the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html) for any arbitrary class, `X`.

I could imagine that this information is not available in the AST, and is only resolved in a specific backend targeting itanium, but other ABI specific information is available (like offsets of any class since the standard does not define class layout).

---

**EDIT - EDIT - EDIT**

After reading the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77723136/how-do-i-get-entire-data-layout-for-a-class-using-libclang?noredirect=1#comment137025163_77723136) by @[Scott McPeak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2659307/scott-mcpeak), I took a peek (see what I did there) at the internals, enough to hack something that seems to work, but likely has major issues.

Here is my somewhat feeble attempt using some of the C++ classes that are used to implement libclang.  I implemented it as an extension of the libclang API, just to make it easier for me to consume and test.  It does what I want, and maybe that makes things a bit more clear for those trying to help.

I'm sure I'm doing something terribly wrong, so I would love a proper answer, especially if what I want can be done somehow with the current libclang API.

It is based on `clang_Type_getOffsetOf`.

Obviously, `CXTypeLayoutError_InvalidFieldName` should be something different, or maybe `CXTypeLayoutError_InvalidBase` of aliased to `CXTypeLayoutError_InvalidFieldNameOrBase`.  In addition, it returns the offset in bits, for consistency with the member offsets, even though I'm 99.9999% sure that there is no way a base class can have an offset in bits.

```cpp
long long clang_Type_getOffsetOfBase(CXType PT,
                                     const CXIdxBaseClassInfo *BaseInfo) {
  // check that PT is not incomplete/dependent
  CXCursor PC = clang_getTypeDeclaration(PT);
  long long Error = validateFieldParentType(PC,PT);
  if (Error < 0)
    return Error;

  // get the record decl for PT
  ASTContext &Ctx = cxtu::getASTUnit(GetTU(PT))->getASTContext();
  const CXXRecordDecl *RD =
        dyn_cast_or_null<CXXRecordDecl>(cxcursor::getCursorDecl(PC));
  if (!RD)
    return CXTypeLayoutError_Invalid;

  // get the record decl for the base
  if (BaseInfo) {
    if (auto Spec = cxcursor::getCursorCXXBaseSpecifier(BaseInfo->cursor)) {
      if (auto BaseDecl = Spec->getType()->getAsCXXRecordDecl()) {
        return Ctx.toBits(
            Ctx.getASTRecordLayout(RD).getBaseClassOffset(BaseDecl));
      }
    }
  }
  return CXTypeLayoutError_InvalidFieldName;
}
```

Comment: Something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/Tz9rjrdc5)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, that is what I am after.  But, I want it for any arbitrary type, and I want it available at compile time.

I'm building a set of type information, and I want this breakdown for any type, some of which is not available in C++ itself (yet), which is why I'm using libclang to parse the code and generate that information.

Comment: The answer to that is probably at the scale of a small library, but assuming you have an `mp_list` of data members and of base classes, you should be able to implement a `consteval` function to reproduce the formula for base class offsets, factoring in alignment and EBO. I'm not aware of any builtin that gives you this as a constant expression. I think two of the trickiest parts of this approach will be detecting a data member attributed with `[[no_unique_address]]` because that applies EBO to the data member, and detecting when EBO does not apply because two adjacent objects are the same type

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood, you're looking for an out-of-band solution? I'm not understanding why it needs to be compile time if you're wanting to use libclang which is runtime...

Comment: I'd settle for a library solution, but I'm not aware of one that will pass a C++ compiler.  There are issues of visibility (most of which can be gotten around), and other inheritance things (private, virtual) that must be dealt with.

Without a library solution, I'm option for using libclang to parse the C++ code and generate C++ code that contains these elements, which can then be used at compile time.

Comment: "libclang" refers to the C API of Clang, while "libtooling" is the name of its C++ API.  The former does not expose everything available in the latter.  Are you only interested in solutions that use what is exposed by libclang?

Comment: @ScottMcPeak - I'd prefer to just use libclang, as I've been told that the lib tooling API can and will break between clang releases.  However, if that is the best way forward, I could write that piece with lib tooling.